# why canplaythrough not working as expected

Tags: javascript

This is what we have in **www.w3school** as the reference:

> The canplaythrough event occurs when the browser estimates it can play
>   through the specified audio/video without having to stop for
>   buffering.

And here is the **developer mozilla** reference:

> The canplaythrough event is fired when the user agent can play the
>   media, and estimates that enough data has been loaded to play the
>   media up to its end without having to stop for further buffering of
>   content.

**without having to stop for buffering!?** I tested a video and I see the video still stops for further buffering. No difference without using `canplaythrough`.

Here is the code:

```
let video = document.createElement('video'); 
content.appendChild(video);
let source = document.createElement('source');
source.src = `clip.mp4`
source.type = 'video/mp4';
video.appendChild(source);
video.load();

video.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
      console.log('Video is loaded..');
});
```

Am I missing something? How to fix this? I want the video only play if it can play through without having to stop for buffering.

**Note**: I'm using the latest update of chrome and I want it to only work in chrome and an HTTPS server.

Any comment is greatly appreciated. feel free to ask me any change and test the code on the server.

Comment: The key word in each set of documentation is "estimates".  It's a guess that it has enough to avoid buffering, not a guarantee.

Comment: The event fires, i.e. the code in the handler function is executed when "_user agent ... estimates that enough data has been loaded to play the media up to its end_" It won't tell you that before the video has been played for a while. Hence you can't use this event for your goal.

Comment: Is there any solution for 'video only play if it can play without having to stop for buffering'?

Comment: I guess you could use a `timeout` to wait a few more seconds past the point Chrome thinks it has enough.  Even then, bandwidth varies over time.  There is no guarantee unless you wait for the entire thing to load.